# ContourPlot Not Producing a Graph

Tags: plotting

The function ContourPlot[sin[x]sinh[y], {x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}] will not show anything in the graph. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: This issue appears only if you haven't read any of the introductory documentation like this one http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/
"The Wolfram Language has about 5000 built-in functions. All have names in which each word starts with a **capital** letter"

Answer (score 3):

I feel stupid. Forgot to capitalize Sin and Sinh.